# Registering a user automatically in WP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I currently have the Participant's Database plugin installed on my WP site (www.nmvolunteer.org). It works great for organizing my volunteers in the back end. Now, I installed the e-Newsletter plugin from WPMU so I can email all of my volunteers with news and events, etc.

I have been able to export the emails from Participant's Database into my e-Newsletter as members, but I don't want to have to do it every time someone signs up. I have learned that the e-Newsletter plugin will automatically add new site users to the newsletter, but the Participant's Database form I'm using does not add my volunteers as site users. Is there a way to alter my form so that it will also automatically add my volunteers as site users?

When asking the PD plugin developer, his response was, "You can use javascript to register the user when they submit their form. You'll need to set up an AJAX callback, then that callback takes the needed user data and registers the user. On your form page, the AJAX interrupts the submission so it can grab it's data and perform the callback, then the submission is allowed to go on as usual, which registers the user with the plugin database. All pretty simple using jQuery."

My issue is that I don't know how to do all that, as I'm clueless when it comes to jQuery, etc. Can anybody walk me through the process? Or does anybody have an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Here's the code for my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fieldstocheck = new Array();
fieldnames = new Array();

function checkform() {
    for (i=0;i<fieldstocheck.length;i++) {
        if (eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].value") == "") {
            alert("Please enter your "+fieldnames[i]);
            eval("document.subscribeform.elements['"+fieldstocheck[i]+"'].focus()");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function addFieldToCheck(value,name) {
    fieldstocheck[fieldstocheck.length] = value;
    fieldnames[fieldnames.length] = name;
}

addfieldtocheck("first_name","first name");
addfieldtocheck("city","city");
addfieldtocheck("last_name","last name");
addfieldtocheck("email","email address");
addfieldtocheck("phone","phone number");
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="signup" name="action"></input>
    <input type="hidden" value="participants-database" name="subsource"></input>
    <input type="hidden" value="?page_id=70" name="shortcode_page"></input><input type="hidden" value="http://nmvolunteer.org/?page_id=78" name="thanks_page"></input>
    <input size="10" id="volformleft" type="text" name="first_name" value="first name" onfocus="if (this.value=='first name') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='first name';}">
    <input size="10" id="volform" type="text" name="last_name" value="last name" onfocus="if (this.value=='last name') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='last name';}">
    <input size="23" id="volform" type="text" name="email" value="email" onfocus="if (this.value=='email') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='email';}">
    <input size="12" id="volform" type="text" name="phone" value="phone" onfocus="if (this.value=='phone') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='phone';}">
    <input size="12" id="volformright" type="text" name="city" value="city" onfocus="if (this.value=='city') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='city';}">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="volunteer" />
    <input id="volformsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="volunteer" onclick="return checkform();">
</form>
```

Comment: This question is extremely broad and should definitely be narrowed down to something more specific. In the meantime, I would suggest an AJAX tutorial such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Comment: Also, try adding some tabbing to your code!

Comment: Once you figure out AJAX, then you can look at [this tutorial](http://sharethingz.com/wordpress/custom-user-registration-in-wordpress-using-ajax/) on adding users via AJAX in Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, guys! @badcook, all I need is a way to make my form submit the user's information to both my Participant's Database and as a site user.